# Prove that, $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1 \over \sqrt n}= 1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, power-series

Actually I have a problem of power series where I am asked to find the Radius of convergence of it. The power series looks like
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {x^n \over n^\sqrt n} $
So I need to calculate the limsup of $n^{1 \over \sqrt n}$, as the sequence $\{n^{1 \over \sqrt n} \}$ converges I have just mentioned limit instead of limsup.
I have tried to prove the limit using a standard limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1 \over n}=1$ using squeeze test.
Can anybody assist me to prove the problem? Only hint will work for me.

Comment: Hint : Show that $\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ tends to $0$ , when $n$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: @Peter, but how it would imply the desired limit. If $\{a_n\}$ is sequence such that $\ln(a_n) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. Does it imply $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: The limit you want follows from $\ln(n^{1/\sqrt{n}})=\frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}}$

Comment: If you prefer, you can substitute $m=\sqrt{n}$, which gives the expression $(m^2)^{1/m}=(m^{1/m})^2$, so you can use the limit you mentioned. This is similar to the approach given in the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}} = (\sqrt n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}\cdot (\sqrt n)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}$$

Comment: it's a better wayout. Thanks